# Change github npm package from private to public

Tags: github, npm, github-package-registry

I have a private repository that contains several git hub npm packages.

I want to change those packages from private to public without changing the repository visibility. I read the documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages) on how to manage github npm packages but I didn't find out any information.

It is possible to have a private repository and the github packages be public or I need to create a package directly on the [npm website](https://www.npmjs.com/)?

Comment: I would create one separate repository for all internal packages and one for all public packages and publish all packages to the correct one of them instead of each package to it's own repo.